# Does Gwt 2.1 Entity Proxy support transparent call to lazy loaded entity relations?

Tags: gwt, lazy-loading, entity-relationship

Well, I have read the document about Entity Proxy [http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html/) . As far as I understood Entity Proxy does not support transparently calling of lazy loaded entity relations. Such as, I have Employee entity, and this entity has supervisor field whose type is Employee, and this field fetch type is lazy.. When I have queried an employee, can I call its getSupervisor method at GWT layer?.. What I expect EmployeeProxy calls transparently getSupervisor method of Employee entity on the server.. Is this the case?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just as you mention it doesn't support lazy loading. It would also be difficult, because while you want to do a `getSupervisor()`, which would return the data, in practice this would mean GWT performs an asynchronous call, and needs a receiver. Technically, it might be be possible to implement something like lazy loading, but due to the asynchrony it would never be possible to simple do a `getSupervisor()`.

Comment: You are right, I have forgot that GWT rpc calls are ascynchronous while asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [gilead project](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=gwt) that might do what you intend.